# Using CopyWebpackPlugin how can I copy files out of node_modules into a folder without it creating a node_modules folder

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm trying to use CopyWebpackPlugin to copy some files out of my node_modules folder and into my build folder.

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin([
  { from: 'node_modules/accounting/**', to: 'vendor/npm/' },
  { from: 'node_modules/angular/**', to: 'vendor/npm/' },
```

I would expect this to output to my build folder `/build/vendor/npm/accounting` and `build/vendor/npm/angular` respectively, but instead a `node_modules` folder is created - the files are actually outputted to `build/vendor/npm/node_modules/accounting`.

How can I prevent the node_modules folder being created and get my expected output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For future reference, the actual correct answer is that I needed context -

```
{ from: 'accounting/**', to: 'vendor/npm', context: 'node_modules' }
```

Answer (score 1):

Include a leading `/` to use the absolute output path

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin([
  { from: 'node_modules/accounting/**', to: '/build/vendor/npm/accounting' },
  { from: 'node_modules/angular/**', to: '/build/vendor/npm/angular' },
],
```

---

Because you're using a glob in your `from` path, the `to` path is relative to the resolved `from` paths. [Github docs](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin#patterns).

[image: screenshot of CopyWebpackPlugin Github documentation]